# Execute a command over multiple files with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have an .exe file which takes two jpg images as arguments and makes some processing on them. So, the command in cmd is:

```
myfile.exe base_image.jpg image1.jpg
```

The first image is standard, while the second one changes and I need this execution to be repeated over 50000 images. So in each iteration the command is modified as

```
myfile.exe base_image.jpg image2.jpg

myfile.exe base_image.jpg image3.jpg

...

myfile.exe base_image.jpg image50000.jpg
```

Rephrasing it I need to execute this: `myfile.exe base_image.jpg image%d.jpg` for d [1,50000]

All the necessary files are placed in the same folder. Is it possible to write a batch file for this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a single command, so you don't really need a batch file

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,50000) do myfile.exe base_image.jpg image%%a.jpg
```

Comment: Don't forget to change %%a to %a if running from the command line without using a batch file.